# IPMI sensor data retrieve from HP Superdome (sx2000) with IPMI tool

Tags: hp, ipmi, hp-ux, ipmitool

i'm trying to extract data sensor from a HP Superdome (sx2000) using the protocol IPMI over LAN. I enabled the IPMI protocol and i setup the password for IPMI protocol on the Superdome.
I'm using ipmiutil tool as IPMI client,the client is connected to the server but it obtains meanigless result(compared with ipmiutil man pages).
Here the output of the command:

```
C:\ipmi>ipmiutil.exe sensor -N <IPADDRESS> -P <IPMI_PASSWORD>
ipmiutil ver 2.83
isensor: version 2.83
Opening lan connection to node <IPADDRESS> ...
Connecting to node  <IPADDRESS>
-- BMC version 1a.03, IPMI version 1.5 
_ID_ SDR_Type_xx ET Own Typ S_Num   Sens_Description   Hex & Interp Reading
0001 SDR EntA 08 0b d2 00 80: 17 00 17 03 d3 00 d3 0f 
0002 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 00 c0: 16 00 16 01 00 00 00 00 
0003 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 01 c0: 16 02 16 03 00 00 00 00 
0004 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 02 c0: 16 04 16 07 00 00 00 00 
0005 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 03 c0: 16 08 16 0b 00 00 00 00 
0006 SDR EntA 08 0b 13 00 80: 0a 00 0a 05 00 00 00 00 
0007 SDR EntA 08 0b 13 01 80: 0a 06 0a 0b 00 00 00 00 
0008 SDR EntA 08 0b 13 02 80: 0a 0c 0a 0d 00 00 00 00 
0009 SDR EntA 08 0b 13 03 80: 0a 0e 0a 0f 00 00 00 00 
000a SDR EntA 08 0b d1 00 80: d0 00 d0 01 00 00 00 00 
000b SDR EntA 08 0b d1 01 80: d0 02 d0 03 00 00 00 00 
000c SDR EntA 08 0b d1 02 80: d0 04 d0 05 00 00 00 00 
000d SDR EntA 08 0b d1 03 80: d0 06 d0 07 00 00 00 00 
000e SDR EntA 08 0b 16 00 80: d6 00 d6 03 1e 02 1e 02 
000f SDR EntA 08 0b 16 01 80: d6 04 d6 07 1e 02 1e 02 
0010 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 02 80: d6 08 d6 0b 1e 03 1e 03 
0011 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 03 80: d6 0c d6 0f 1e 03 1e 03 
0012 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 04 80: d6 10 d6 13 1e 04 1e 04 
0013 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 05 80: d6 14 d6 17 1e 05 1e 05 
0014 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 06 80: d6 18 d6 1b 1e 06 1e 06 
0015 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 07 80: d6 1c d6 1f 1e 07 1e 07 
0016 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 08 80: d6 20 d6 23 1e 08 1e 08 
0017 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 09 80: d6 24 d6 27 1e 09 1e 09 
0018 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 0a 80: d6 28 d6 2b 1e 0a 1e 0a 
0019 SDR EntA 08 0b 16 0b 80: d6 2c d6 2f 1e 0b 1e 0b 
001a SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 00 80: 1d 00 1d 03 00 00 00 00 
001b SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 01 80: 1d 04 1d 07 00 00 00 00 
001c SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 02 80: 1d 08 1d 0c 00 00 00 00 
001d SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 03 80: 1d 0d 1d 11 00 00 00 00 
001e SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 04 80: 1d 12 1d 15 00 00 00 00 
001f SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 05 80: 1d 16 1d 19 00 00 00 00 
0020 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 06 80: 1d 1a 1d 1d 00 00 00 00 
0021 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 07 80: 1d 1e 1d 21 00 00 00 00 
0022 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 08 80: 1d 22 1d 25 00 00 00 00 
0023 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 09 80: 1d 26 1d 29 00 00 00 00 
0024 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 0a 80: 1d 2a 1d 2d 00 00 00 00 
0025 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 0b 80: 1d 2e 1d 31 00 00 00 00 
0026 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 0c 80: 1d 32 1d 33 00 00 00 00 
0027 SDR EntA 08 0b 1e 0d 80: 1d 34 1d 35 00 00 00 00 
0028 SDR EntA 08 0b 07 00 80: d5 00 d5 07 13 04 13 04 
0029 SDR EntA 08 0b 07 01 80: d5 08 d5 0f 13 05 13 05 
002a SDR EntA 08 0b d7 00 80: d8 00 d8 01 00 00 00 00 
002b SDR EntA 08 0b d7 01 80: d8 02 d8 03 00 00 00 00 
002c SDR EntA 08 0b 13 04 80: 14 00 14 01 00 00 00 00 
002d SDR EntA 08 0b 13 05 80: 14 02 14 03 00 00 00 00 
002e SDR EntA 08 0b 12 00 c0: 09 00 09 03 00 00 00 00 
002f SDR EntA 08 0b 12 01 c0: 09 04 09 07 00 00 00 00 
0030 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 02 c0: 09 08 09 0b 00 00 00 00 
0031 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 03 c0: 09 0c 09 0f 00 00 00 00 
0032 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 04 c0: 09 10 09 13 00 00 00 00 
0033 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 05 c0: 09 14 09 17 00 00 00 00 
0034 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 06 c0: 09 18 09 1b 00 00 00 00 
0035 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 07 c0: 09 1c 09 1f 00 00 00 00 
0036 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 08 c0: 09 20 09 23 00 00 00 00 
0037 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 09 c0: 09 24 09 27 00 00 00 00 
0038 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 0a c0: 09 28 09 2b 00 00 00 00 
0039 SDR EntA 08 0b 12 0b c0: 09 2c 09 2f 00 00 00 00 
003a SDR EntA 08 0b 12 0c c0: 09 30 09 33 00 00 00 00 
003b SDR EntA 08 0b 12 0d c0: 09 34 09 37 00 00 00 00 
003c SDR EntA 08 0b 12 0e c0: 09 38 09 3b 00 00 00 00 
003d SDR EntA 08 0b 12 0f c0: 09 3c 09 3f 00 00 00 00 
003e SDR EntA 08 0b 17 00 40: 0e 00 1e 00 07 00 06 00 
003f SDR EntA 08 0b 17 00 40: 11 00 11 04 00 00 00 00 
0040 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 01 40: 0e 01 1e 01 07 01 00 00 
0041 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 01 40: 11 01 11 05 00 00 00 00 
0042 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 02 40: 0e 02 1e 0c 11 02 11 06 
0043 SDR EntA 08 0b 17 03 40: 0e 03 1e 0d 11 03 11 07 
.... (several line like the previous)
```

Can you know which the problem is? Or how can i extract useful information from this output?

Comment: I'm going to guess there's not too many people here who have worked with a superdome...

Comment: Are HP Support no use here?

Comment: HP doesn't release any software to retrieve sensor data using IPMI for this server. The documentation describe that the server supports IPMI over Lan 1.5 in order to retrieve sensors' data.

Comment: Can you use SNMP instead?

Comment: I can use only IPMI over LAN, it's a requisite.

Comment: Hi @NoNoNo did you get a resolution on this? I'm also working on a similar requirement for HP Superdome2. It would be great if you can share more details around this.

Comment: Hi @AnkitJaiswal, sorry I don't work anymore on HP Superdome servers and if I remember well I haven't found a solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Define useful. Are you looking for something human readable?

```
ipmiutil.exe sensor -c -N <address> -P <password>
```

Comment: I'm looking something that I can undenstand in any format. I need to obtain for example which is the current fan speed, the temperature sensor value? In the manual http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/docs/UserGuide paragraph 3.13 there is a example with a output row for each sensor and the name of the sensor is written in english text. In my output there isn't any sensor name and any sensor value.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade ipmi on the server, at least to version 2. Or is there a reason why you are using 1.5?

Comment: Oh, and what does `sensor -c` show?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a piece of kit that I have had direct experience with, however you might have more luck decoding the data format using one of the native HP remote IPMI tools from their downloads site.

The have a tool called the "Event Information Tool (EIT)"   from the HP superdome software downloads;
https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=EIT

which includes a facility to obtain the IPMI log from a remote system;

> "IPMI Log Acquirer The IPMI Log Acquirer tool obtains information
>   about the Forward Progress Logs (FPL) present on a remote IPMI system.
>
> IPMI Event Viewer The IPMI Event Viewer tool displays the low-level
>   system log information, such as the status of a component,
>   configuration of a processor, and so on. "

If you cant get hold of that EIT tool for the HP superdome (it looks like a free tool if you are a customer), there are likely similar tools that you can access via your HP password associated with the support contract for the unit.

Answer (score 0):

Your [HP Superdome sx2000](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11717_div/11717_div.HTML) *may* have an ILO2 interface available to you on the main board. Is this the case? If so, you should be able to query the [ILO2 management device](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01936251/c01936251.pdf) and parse the output in order to obtain sensor data.

Comment: The second link seems broken. Do you have a new link or may be some more pointers?

Comment: Does ILO use IPMI internally?