# Pulling logs from HP Superdome 2

Tags: hp, ipmi, ilo, hpe

I'm trying to pull some event and hardware failure logs from HP Superdome 2 servers (through some scripts) for some analysis. I need this data with timestamp of the event/failure. I came across a few suggestions like IPMI, ILO and RedFish.

IPMI option seems to require some extra configuration or needs to be enabled.
RedFish does not seem to be supported as of now on HP Superdome.

ILO Seems to be the only option, but I could not find any programming interface/API to interact with it with my script.

Has anyone done a similar stuff or can provide me some pointers?

**UPDATE**:

Below question seems to be around a similar effort but does not have an accepted answer:

[IPMI sensor data retrieve from HP Superdome (sx2000) with IPMI tool](https://serverfault.com/questions/386115/ipmi-sensor-data-retrieve-from-hp-superdome-sx2000-with-ipmi-tool?noredirect=1#comment1215281_386115)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this setup remote syslog server and send logs to this server from ILO.

You can read more [there](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-a00045612en_us&docLocale=en_US)

Another way check SNMP alerts features of the ILO

There another more [information](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-a00045581en_us&docLocale=en_US)

Comment: I'm unable to find both these options on HPE Superdome. I've logged in through Onboard Administrator. Looks like I'm missing something?